# How do I get the sum of online users from the last 500 records?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table in user_statistics. New records appear in it every now and then. I want to get the sum of one column from the last 500 records. How can I achieve it?

I tried it, but it doesn't work:

```
    UserStatistics::select(DB::raw('SUM(rooms_online) as rooms_online'))
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->take(User::count())
        ->get();
```

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select SUM(rooms_online) as rooms_onlinefrom `user_statistics` order by `id` desc limit 1)

When I add **groupBy**, I will not get the sum, but all records separately.

Can I get guidance on how to do it?

Comment: I dont laravel, but i'd try to drop the `take()` and add `limit(500)`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: as the error shows, you have to add a groupBy()

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE user_statistics` and paste the result into your question. Also, post an illustration of your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can [take](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#skip-take) the [latest](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#latest-oldest) 500 rows:

```
$rooms_online=DB::table('user_statistics')->latest()->take(500)->sum('rooms_online');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to query the sum of latest 500, you can try the code below.

```
UserStatistic::orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(500)->sum('rooms_online');
```